# Created a new activity - Actionbar won't show up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've just created a new application. The main activity contains a button which when pressed starts a new activity like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.activity_main_add:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

This is how the **Activity2** looks like:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task);
}
}
```

The problem now is that the main activity shows the actionbar, but the second activity won't.
I don't know where the problem could be, any suggestions? Here's the **manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.test" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/activity_2">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_settings">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here's the **style**:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second `Activity` to:

```
public class Activity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task);
    }
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Already upvoted this answer, but had to wait 10min to mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try extending ActionBarActivity instead of Activity.